# C++ 11 std::binomial_distribution is unstable

Tags: c++, c++11, random

When using `std::binomial_distribution` implemented by `clang++`, I am seeing some very unhappy behaviour:

```
default_random_engine rng;

vector<double> p{0.2500000000000000000000000000000000000000,
                 0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929395,
                 0.5999999999999999777955395074968691915274,
                 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263};

for (auto &i : p) {
  binomial_distribution<int> binom(1000, i);
  cout << binom(rng) << " ≈ " << 1000 * i << endl;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
254 ≈ 250
340 ≈ 333.333
598 ≈ 600
628 ≈ 1000 # WAT? - should be around 1000
```

Quite curiously, if you try to call `binomial_distribution<int>(100, p[3])`, it hangs forever. This latter behaviour later is undesirable, but expected - the probability of success should not exceed `1`.

In case you are wondering, the above values of `p` come from generating multinomial variates using [conditional binomial method](https://fossies.org/dox/gsl-2.1/multinomial_8c_source.html) in adapting `gsl_ran_multinomial`.

My compiler is `clang++` under `El Capitan 10.11.4`

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already stated, `p` (the probability of success) must be less than or equal to 1.  It seems that passing an invalid value as you are doing, with the current implementation in Clang, makes it re-use the previous value (0.5999 in your case).

In short, you seem to be invoking undefined behavior.  Anything could happen.  Boost's implementation is [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/binomial_dist.html#math_toolkit.dist.dist_ref.dists.binomial_dist.construct) as throwing an exception when `p` is out of bounds.

Comment: Makes sense. I suppose I really wanted to complain.